# Height of the wrapper not working on the container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a background video with the fixed height of 700px without affecting the aspect ratio. video can crop. My issue is that the full height of the video is showing even I have provided a height of 700 px. Here is the code:

```
<div class="video-container">
  <div class="video-overlay-text">
    <h1>Some heading</h1>
    <p>Sentence</p>               
  </div>
  <video autoplay loop muted id="video-bg">
    <source src="homepage-video-mp4_1.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> 
  </video>
</div>
```

here is the CSS:

```
#video-bg {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: transparent url(video-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
video {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}  
.video-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}    
.video-overlay-text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: auto;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 4%;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;   
}    
.video-overlay-text h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size:34px;
  line-height: 36px;
}    
.video-overlay-text p {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

I have tried everything. Sometimes the mobile view gets cut and the text moves way up.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/

Comment: @Abhi, i can't seem to have the problem. Check the pen https://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/eRXNVq let me know what issue are you facing.

Answer (score 1):

I have added max-height which will be helpful for all screen sizes. Also added a demo text to show the limit of the video. Hope this helps.

```css
#video-bg {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: transparent url(video-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

video {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.video-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.video-overlay-text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: auto;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 4%;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.video-overlay-text h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 34px;
  line-height: 36px;
}

.video-overlay-text p {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <div class="video-overlay-text">
    <h1>Some heading</h1>
    <p>Sentence</p>
  </div>
  <video autoplay loop muted id="video-bg">
<source src="//ak3.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/2743133/preview/stock-footage-shanghai-china-circa-july-timelapse-video-of-shanghai-china-skyline-at-sunset-circa-july.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> 



    </video>
</div>

<h2>Hello</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The issue is that it is working on my local machine but when i move the code to development site it is not working. So its showing full height of the video. (Note: I am creating a custom page for a shopify website

Comment: I like your answer very much but the whole idea of video backgrounds [doesn't scale well on large screens.](https://image.ibb.co/hVfsZa/Capture.png)

Comment: @Ihazkode , well if you read the question asked, the croping of video is not a problem. That's why i gave this solution.

Comment: @AbhiS, Can you explain the full height? Of course, the video is going to be full height always but in your situation, it only shows in the limited height you provided. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I read the question and your answer is a good answer for the question as it it is and that's why I upvoted it. I was making an observation.

Comment: @hunzaboy Let me explain. The video size is 1920px by 1080px and putting it in a container of 600px.. The code you have shown above works fine at my local machine as well but not on the development site.

Comment: @Ihazkode oh ok :)